# BigQuery 1.2.0.1000 JDBC driver packages a lot of JAR files

Tags: google-bigquery

Unlike prior versions of SIMBA JDBC driver, Version 1.2.0.1000 seems to come with ~57 JAR files and no documentation to suggest that they are all required.

Does anyone know if they are or if this might be a packaging error by SIMBA?

I Reviewed the release notes/docs from SIMBA that came with this release but couldn't find an answer to this question.

Download the [BigQuery driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/), unzip it and compare contents to previous releases.

Comment: can you please tell us if you got any specific error message which concerns you or is this just a general question?

Comment: Given all prior driver releases included only 7 jar files and the current 57 it seems dubious. So per question, is SIMBA intending to package 57 JAR files, are they all mandatory for the driver or some optional. If some are optional, which and when would they be required etc.

Comment: I suggest you will contact SIMBA support team directly on this matter